# Is there any way I can use Moose::Exporter from within a Moose object?

Tags: perl, export, moose

I'm looking for a way to set up some helper methods from within a parent [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) class, rather than a standalone utility class. If it is possible, it would be a more transparent way of adding Moose sugar to modules, as it does not require explicitly requiring any helper modules (as everything would come via the `extends` declaration).

Based on the [example provided in the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Exporter#SYNOPSIS), this is roughly what I am going for:

```
package Parent;

use Moose;

Moose::Exporter->setup_import_methods(
    with_meta => [ 'has_rw' ],
    as_is     => [ 'thing' ],
    also      => 'Moose',
);

sub has_rw {
    my ( $meta, $name, %options ) = @_;
    $meta->add_attribute(
        $name,
        is => 'rw',
        %options,
    );
}

# then later ...
package Child;

use Moose;
extends 'Parent';

has 'name';
has_rw 'size';
thing;
```

However this does not work:

```
perl -I. -MChild -wle'$obj = Child->new(size => 1); print $obj->size'
```

```
String found where operator expected at Child.pm line 10, near "has_rw 'size'"
        (Do you need to predeclare has_rw?)
syntax error at Child.pm line 10, near "has_rw 'size'"
Bareword "thing" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at Child.pm line 12.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

PS. I've also tried moving the export magic into a role (`with Role;` rather than `extends Parent;`) but the same errors occur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't supported, and there is a good reason why. A Class or a Role are not the same as sugar methods, and at some level different things should be different. If your problem is having to "use" Moose + A Custom  Sugar package then you can solve that by simply having your custom sugar package export Moose as well, stealing from your example:

```
package MySugar;
use strict;
use Moose::Exporter;

Moose::Exporter->setup_import_methods(
    with_meta => [ 'has_rw' ],
    as_is     => [ 'thing' ],
    also      => 'Moose',
);

sub has_rw {
    my ( $meta, $name, %options ) = @_;
    $meta->add_attribute(
        $name,
        is => 'rw',
        %options,
    );
}
```

Then you simply say:

```
package MyApp;
use MySugar; # imports everything from Moose + has_rw and thing    
extends(Parent);

has_rw 'name';
has 'size';
thing;
```

This is how `MooseX::POE` works, as well as several other packages. I for one would argue against having `extends` bring in the sugar like you're suggesting here because a Class is not a bundle of sugar functions, and the two really should never be confused.

UPDATE: To bring in both at once the cleanest approach is to rework Parent as a role that is applied to Moose::Object.

```
package Parent::Methods;
use 5.10.0;
use Moose::Role;

sub something_special { say 'sparkles' }
```

Then we simply change the call to Moose::Exporter in MySugar to look like

```
Moose::Exporter->setup_import_methods(
    apply_base_class_roles => 'Parent::Methods',
    with_meta              => ['has_rw'],
    as_is                  => ['thing'],
    also                   => 'Moose',
);
```

Now you can simply say

```
package MyApp;
use MySugar; 

has_rw 'name';
has 'size';
thing;

package main;
MyApp->new->something_special; # prints sparkles
```

Which is I believe the final detail you were wanting.

Comment: What I was looking for is to combine `Parent` and `MySugar` together into one class, since the sugar is specifically designed to build on components defined in `Parent`. However it's not the end of the world to define them and bring them in separately.. I just don't want to separate them as two separate components because they aren't. They should be brought in together or not at all.

Comment: Yup, Moose::Exporter will let you bring both in together. Defining them both in one class is a bad idea in my opinion because it conflates two different things that really should be separate.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an example of bringing in both together using the reccomended style. If you want more than this, I suggest coming past #moose on irc.perl.org or asking the Moose mailing list for specific questions.

Comment: @perigrin: as it turns out I had to rework my entire structure due to a limitation with class attributes and inheritance, so now I'm not using 'extends' at all but bringing in all functionality with roles. I cannot use apply_base_class_roles as I'm using parameterized roles; however it's not inelegant to simply do `use MySugar; with 'Role::blah' => { params... };`. :)

Comment: @Ether you might talk with the people on #moose about allowing Paramaterized Roles to work as Traits, I'm not sure what the limitation there is but someone might have an elegant solution.